# A Crozier Riddle

Tags: riddle, wordplay

**This is a new kind of riddle called a Crozier riddle. Here are the rules:**

The first letter of each of the answers must be put together and unscrambled to reveal a final word. Here are the clues: (They will start off easy and get increasingly harder)

> 1. Something a horse says.
> 2. The largest living land animal.
> 3. Ten letter name for someone’s job.
> 4. A flashcard website that makes simple learning tools to help students study.
> 5. An alternative sugar in gum that is not sugar or aspartame.
> 6. A song about a good girl gone bad that talks about the Dow.
> 7. A ten letter word for a problem that resulted from a doctor.

**The final unscrambled word will be seven letters: _ _ _ _ _ _ _**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Answers to hints(partial):

> 1. Neigh
> 2. Elephant
> 3. Occupation
> 4. Quizlet
> 5. maltitol, mannitol, sorbitol or **xylitol**(reverse solved)
> 6. Umbrella(by Rihanna)
> 7. Iatrogenic (Thanks puzzledPig!)

Which anagram to

> Equinox

Comment: ah, you snuck in right before me...

Comment: These are correct so far, keep going! :)

Comment: Congratulations! You solved it!

Answer (score 4):

Partial:

Something a horse says.

> Neigh

The largest living land animal.

> Elephant

Ten letter name for someone’s job.

> Occupation

A flashcard website that makes simple learning tools to help students study.

> Quizlet

A ten letter word for a problem that resulted from a doctor.

> Iatrogenic (thanks [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iatrogenesis))

Comment: hehe sniped oops

Comment: These are correct so far, keep going! :)