# Another Crozier Puzzle

Tags: word

A “*Crozier*” Riddle. I saw [this](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/64039/a-crozier-riddle) one yesterday and I wanted to create my own! You have to use the first letter of each word suggested in the hints and then scramble those letters to find the 8 letter word.

> 1. Spanish plantation/mine/factory similar to a Roman villa.
> 2. A toy that goes up and down.
> 3. The “bear” country.
> 4. I represent un-real things.
> 5. Who claims he wants to “catch them all”.
> 6. What you hold on *Jeopardy!*
> 7. The name when ground moves away from each other.
> 8. Fearless, Speak Now, Reputation.

**I have 8 letters _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _.**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Some of these were taken from the earlier partial solutions.

1:

> Hacienda = h

2:

> yo-yo = y

3:

> Russia = r

4:

> i = i

5:

> Ash = a

6:

> buzzer = b

7:

> divergent earthquake = d

8:

> Taylor swift = t

That means the answer is

> birthday

Comment: Great Job those are correct! :D

Answer (score 3):

Partial Answer:

1:

> Hacienda

8:

> Taylor Swift

Comment: Yup that is correct :D good job

Answer (score 2):

1 is

> (Currently unknown)

2 is

> A yo-yo: a cylinder toy attached to string that bob up and down (more or less)

5 is

> Ash, an avid Pokémon trainer from the Pokémon TV show

7 is

> An earthquake, or more specifically, a divergent earthquake

Comment: I added hints to make #1 clearer.

Comment: I'm guessing that 3 is Alaska